# preserve transparency in custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a custom list view to make 3d list view. but when using

```
Bitmap bitmap = child.getDrawingCache();
```

inside `drawChild` function the transparency of the view is lost and the transparent pixels are black. if i create an new bitmap for each `drawChild` the listview becomes slow and is not smooth. is there any way in which i can preserve the transparency while using the `getDrawingCache()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found the answer. To Preserve the transparency we have to override the `getDrawingCache()` method of our View.